# A question about the term "depressed cubic"

Tags: terminology

The depressed cubic equation is a cubic equation of the form $x^3+px+q=0$. This expression sounds strange especially for someone that English is not his mother tongue. Why this equation is called "depressed"? What is so depressing in it? Thanks!

Comment: The coefficient of the quadratic term has been "depressed" to zero.

Comment: In the Merriam-Webster dictionary the third meaning of depress is "press down". So the equation is not sad but downgraded.

Comment: To depress something is to push it downward.$\qquad$

Comment: I'd like using **reduced cubic**.  See [another answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616213/how-to-ind-the-complex-roots-of-y3-frac13y-frac2527/1617160#1617160) of mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why this equation is called "depressed"?

It is from latin [deprimitur](https://glosbe.com/la/en/deprimitur) : *lowered*.

It seems that the terminology was intoduced by [François Viète](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Vi%C3%A8te) (1540 – 1603) into his posthumous :

- [Francisci Vietae Fontenaeensis ab aequationum recognitione et emendatione](https://books.google.it/books?id=Q4dbiZ0apcUC&pg=PA79) (1615), page 79:

> Anastrophe [*anastrophe*] is the transformation of inverse negative equations into their correlatives. It is carried out so that the original equation, with the help of its correlative, can be reduced [*reducatur ad depressiorem*] [...] to a lower [power] and, therefore, be more easily solved. [...] The work of anastrophe is performed this way : [...] and the equation, otherwise soluble only with difficulty, can depressed [*deprimitur*] to one that is easily solved by means of a pretty operation.

Answer (score 4):

The coefficient of the quadratic term has been "depressed" to zero:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Reduction_to_a_depressed_cubic

Depress also has the meaning of "reduce":

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/depress