# How to derive cubic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Using completing the square method we can derive a formula $ax^2+bx+c=0$ for the quadratic equation to $$x={-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}\over 2a}$$

I am sure I haven't sees it in any book talking about deriving the cubic equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ using the method of completing the square or the cube.

So how did they derive the cubic formula to solve the cubic equation?

Comment: You can find it in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients)

Comment: see here https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/

Comment: See my answer [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616213/how-to-find-the-complex-roots-of-y3-frac13y-frac2527/1617160#1617160)