# Apply Cardano's method to find the roots of $f(x)=x^3 - 6x + 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, cubics

> Apply Cardano's method to find the roots of $f(x) = x^3 − 6x + 4$

There was a part a) to this question with $f(x)=x^3 - 6x - 6$ which yielded a positive number under the square root using Cardano's method. I was able to get the real roots for that question.

The difference is in this cubic, when I used Cardano's method I got a negative under the square root implying complex roots.

I have $(-4 \pm 4i) / 2$ using Cardano's formula. I am not really sure where to go from here as I haven't done a Cardano problem of this type.

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: You can proceed like in [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616213/how-to-find-the-complex-roots-of-y3-frac13y-frac2527?rq=1).

Comment: If you apply polynomial division by the quadratic given the 2 roots, you obtain the third : it is the sum.